# How can I resize and position a widget in the kv language?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to resize an image so it's in the left corner, I've been playing around with it and I can't get my head around this code works, before I put it in the left corner I want to resize to size of the green rectangle to just see how it works but I'm not getting that.

[image]

```
#:kivy 1.9.0
GridLayout:
    rows: 1

    LeftArea:
    RightArea:

<LeftArea@FloatLayout>:

    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 0, 1, 0
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    Image:
        source: 'moneyswags.gif'
        size: self.size
        pos: self.pos
```

Comment: Try `self.parent.size` and `self.parent.pos`

Comment: Thanks but that just gives me same result, I've alo tried root instead of self which was the same result.

Comment: Check [`allow_stretch: True`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.image.html#kivy.uix.image.Image.allow_stretch) and [`keep_ratio: False`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.image.html#kivy.uix.image.Image.keep_ratio)

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need is written here: [Image](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.image.html#kivy.uix.image.Image)

Add `allow_stretch: True` to the image, and it will cover the entire parent float layout.

Also, defining `size: self.size` and `pos: self.pos` inside the Image does nothing. In case of canvas, `self` refers to the widget on which you are drawing (in this case, float layout).